# Insert a newline without entering in insert mode, vim

Tags: vim, newline, key-bindings, keymapping

I want insert newlines in normal mode in vim using <kbd>Shift-Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd>. I try some solutions and mixing solutions from [Vim Wikia - Insert newline without entering insert mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode) but <kbd>Shift-Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd> didn't respond:

```
" put a new line before or after to this line
nnoremap <S-CR> m`o<Esc>``
nnoremap <C-CR> m`O<Esc>``

" reverse J command
nnoremap <C-J> vaW<Esc>Bi<CR><Esc>k:s/\s\+$//<CR>$
```

Comment: What is your `$TERM` (if *nix)?

Comment: `echo $TERM` -> `xterm` Why?

Comment: It may be relevant how the keys are interpreted. Do you use screen or tmux aswell? That being said, I tried a couple of the alternatives, and it would only work for `map <CR> o<Esc>` here.

Comment: well, I don't use screen or tmux with vim. And yes, `map <CR> o<Esc>` work. But, how map `O<Esc>`? . I'm sorry by my bad english

Answer (score 97):

My alternative is using `oo` (resp. `OO`) to insert a new line under (resp. over) the current through this mapping:
`nmap oo o<Esc>k`
(resp. `nmap OO O<Esc>j`)

Comment: Great answer. Just 'o' works and goes to insert mode too. Thanks

Comment: The thing that was bothering me most with the other answers was the shortcut. This one favors my preferences.

Comment: I did **nmap <C-S-J> o<Esc>k** since Shift+J deletes newline.

Comment: Another enhancement is to use ```nmap oo m`o<Esc>`` ``` and ```nmap OO m`O<Esc>`` ``` to preserve cursor position when opening newlines into different indentation levels, as described in [these comments](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode).

Comment: You may also want to use a shorter timeout value than the default 1-second to more quickly go into insert mode with plain `o` and `O`. I like `set timeoutlen=200`. You'll just need to press the double `oo` quick enough, and this shrinks the window to execute other non-blocking time-outable commands sequences too.

Answer (score 31):

Yank an empty line and shift-paste it:

Starting with cursor on empty line:

```
yy + (shift + p)
```

"yy" yanks the line, and "shift + p" insert it below, without entering insert mode.

Comment: `(shift + y) then p` as alternative

Answer (score 10):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today. (This particular case should work in GVIM, though.) Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/Ym6D-kWIsyo).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: It's mostly due to historical reasons, but unfortunately quite hard to change.

Answer (score 4):

How about this if you just don't want to press ESC

```
yypd$
```

Comment: since I have `D` to delete to the end of line, mine would be `yypD`

Comment: The downside to this is you lose whatever is in your clipboard (yankboard? not sure what it's called in vi(m))

Comment: yypdd works well in different enviroments.

Comment: @DrBeco better yet: `YpD` (below) or `YPD` (above). Is a good aproach, but the problem is it doesn't take the cursor back to its initial position

Comment: yankboard is absolutely hilarious, I'm only going to refer to it as that from now on.

Comment: @zshift it's called a register.

Answer (score 2):

I use :s/\n/\r\r/g (subsitute the newline with two newlines, which is the same as "o").

Comment: needed for this a chained cabbrev

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
nmap <CR> :a<CR><CR>.<CR>
```

I tried `nmap <CR> o<Esc>`, but it made UI glitchy as it was switching to insert mode and back.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy an empty line to a register and use that. I have built the habit of copying a new line to the `n` register.
You can copy a new line to a register, in this case `n` using:
`"ny`
You can paste the new line anywhere without leaving normal mode like:
`"np`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a newline without the cursor jumping around you can:

(Written in Lua for Neovim, but you could convert it to Vim script.)

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<CR>", "mao<esc>0<S-d>`a<cmd>delmarks a<cr>", { desc = "Add new line below" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "<S-CR>", "maO<esc>0<S-d>`a<cmd>delmarks a<cr>", { desc = "Add new line above" })
```

This uses marks to preserve your line and column position. And deletes any characters that are automatically added when opening a new line (such as comment characters).

1. `ma`: mark current cursor position.
2. `o`: open a new line and enter insert mode.
3. `<esc>`: enter normal mode.
4. `0<S-d>`: go to the beginning of the line and empty it.
5. `` `a ``: go to the original marked cursor location.
6. `<cmd>delmarks a<cr>`: delete the mark.

Note that if you want to avoid mapping the carriage return in non-normal windows (e.g. hitting enter in the quickfix list should still take you to the file) you can:

```lua
-- Set keymap for normal windows only (e.g. not quickfix)
local normal_window_keymap = function(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
  local merged_opts = vim.tbl_extend("force", { noremap = true, expr = true }, opts or {})

  vim.keymap.set(mode, lhs, function()
    local buftype = vim.fn.win_gettype()
    return buftype == "" and rhs or lhs
  end, merged_opts)
end

-- Open new line (like o/O) without moving the cursor, without entering insert mode and removing any characters
normal_window_keymap("n", "<CR>", "mao<esc>0<S-d>`a<cmd>delmarks a<cr>", { desc = "Add new line below" })
normal_window_keymap("n", "<S-CR>", "maO<esc>0<S-d>`a<cmd>delmarks a<cr>", { desc = "Add new line above" })
```

Comment: Am I missing something, going back to the original mark and then deleting the mark? This just puts you back where you started? (I think the point was to be on the next line in normal mode)

Answer (score -3):

You can use a hack to do this.

In edit mode, you can use `p` to paste the current clipboard. Since `o` adds a newline, you can use `o<ESC>ddp` to add a new line below the cursor; from there, `p` will add a new line until you delete something else.