# why when i press enter my vim(gvim) show ^M in normal mode?

Tags: vim

there is a strange Phenomenon of my vim(gvim).
just as i said in title, when i press enter, it'll show ^M at lower right. and disappear after about 1sec, then it'll act as it should be. as if it's the first charactor of some "multi-charactor" command.

here are some lines in my vimrc.
    `au FileType * nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <C-]>`
    `let mapleader = "\<space>"`
    `set encoding=utf-8`
    `set fencs=utf-8,ucs-bom,shift-jis,gb18030,gbk,gb2312,cp936`
    `set fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,chinese`
    `set ffs=unix,dos,mac`

can someone tell me how to fix it?

thanks for Pinpin. but my problem occurs in normal mode.

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Have you seen this **[post](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/)** about odd ^M characters?

Comment: yes, i've seen it. but it's not the problem i met.  my problem occurs in normal mode. when i press enter in insert mode, it doesn't show the ^M charcactor.

Comment: Does the behavior go away if you do `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: yes, it's gone. does this mean this occured because one of my plugin?

Comment: i tried "-u NORC" "--noplugin". and it seem to be some command in my vimrc caused it.

Comment: i found the reason. there some nnoremap <C-m> maps in my vimrc.which i meant to be map CTRL+m. thanks, @jthill ,can you answer this question so that i can choose your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[For internal reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134808/813602), `<C-M>` is the same as `<CR>` (or `<Enter>`). The reason that Vim briefly displays the key in the bottom right corner is that it is waiting for further keys (and you have `:set showcmd`), because **you have a mapping that begins with Enter**.

```
:nmap <CR>
```

(or `:nmap <C-m>`) will list it. To avoid the delay, you need to get rid of it / choose another key for it.